# how to run multiple commands with awk via ssh?

Tags: shell-script, ssh, quoting

I am having difficulty on the command below. Something is not right with the awk command. I tried putting backslash but still no good.
Anyone can pin point where is my syntax gone wrong?

```
for i in $(cat db_hostlist2.txt | grep -v '^#'); do
  echo "Checking for $i";
  ssh admin@$i '
    . ./.bashrc; echo "Hostname : `hostname`";
    echo -e "Total DB is : `ps -ef | grep smon | grep -v grep | wc -l`\n";
    echo -e "Total DB is : \n`ps -ef | grep smon | grep -v grep |awk -F_ '{print $3}'`\n"
  ';
done
```

Output:

```
Hostname : TEST123
Total DB is : 3

awk: cmd. line:1: {print
awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ unexpected newline or end of string
Total DB is :
```

Comment: awk's `'` interferes with ssh's `'` try escaping those with \

Answer (score 1):

```
for HOST in $(grep -v '^#' db_hostlist2.txt)
do
        echo "Checking for $HOST"
        ssh admin@$HOST <<EOF
echo "Hostname : " \$(hostname)
echo -e "Total DB is : \$(ps -ef | grep smon | grep -v grep | wc -l)\n"
echo -e "Total DB is : \n\$(ps -ef | grep smon | grep -v grep |awk -F_ '{print \$3}')\n"
EOF
        echo "$HOST Complete"
done
```

Everything between the two EOF's gets treated normally and executed remotely, no need for escaping special characters, except for when using $(cmd) to execute a remote command. You can put local variables in there if you'd like.

Comment: it sounds to mee that $(cmd) within here document will be executed locally.

Comment: You're right, I modified the answer to reflect that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

this seems over complicated.

my proposal :

```
for i in $(cat db_hostlist2.txt | grep -v '^#')
do 
     echo "Checking for $i"
     ssh admin@$i '. ./.bashrc;   
          echo "Hostname : "hostname ;
          echo -e "Total DB is : " ;
          ps -ef | grep -c [s]mon ;
          echo " DB are : " \
          ps -ef | grep [s]mon  |awk -F_ \'{print $3}\' ' 
 done
```

where

- thou shalt not be worry over new line inside single quote. (newline inside ' are OK)
- `grep smon | grep -v grep` is replace by `grep [s]mon` which doesn't grep itself.
- `ps -ef | grep smon | grep -v grep | wc -l` is replace by `ps -ef | grep -c [s]mon` which return count of items.
- `echo -e "text`a command`\n"` is replaced by `echo text ; a command` (why use -e and add \n ? also most command produce a newline).

Comment: Doesn't work. You can't use `\'` to quote a single quote inside single quotes (you can use `'\''`). Your code is also missing some backticks, maybe because you used the version of the question broken by an edit instead of the original.

Comment: well, but at least, can I save `grep [s]mon` instead of `grep smon| grep -v grep` ?

Comment: Just make it `pgrep smon` or `pidof smon` if it's non-embedded Linux.

Comment: Just make it `ps -C smon` and do not invent complexities where they are not needed :)